# onActivityResult is not called for Contacts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I need to start the default contact intent and get the values of the selected contact. I am using the following code for start the Contact intent.

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
 ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

But the onActivityResult method not at all called. Is there any flags have to set for the intent.?

Comment: remove this intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  then try

Comment: Already tried. But onAcvtivityResult not called at all.

Comment: one more thing in manifest file In your current activity tag have u added android:launchMode if added just removed it & try again

Comment: I am not added launchMode for this contact activity.

Comment: try final Uri uriContact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
                Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);
                startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, 100);

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the onActivityResult is not called.

Answer (score 1):

The following code triggers the onActivityResult method.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```